# Azure Machine Learning Studio: how to add a dataset from a local Excel file?

Tags: excel, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Despite prominent how-to posts on how to add datasets to Azure Machine Learning that say Excel is supported, when I actually go to add a dataset and select a local Excel file, there's no option for "Excel" in the required datatype property dropdown. I'm surprised that Azure wouldn't support Excel (right?) - am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown list indicates the "Destination" datatype for the new DATASET file you are creating, not the source type.

I just uploaded a `.xlsx` file successfully into a `.CSV` file in AML.

Comment: Right. I have seen that which doesn't really say that Excel isn't supported, but I've also seen explicit documentation that says Excel is supported. Since I have 121 separate files to load and it also doesn't allow you to choose multiple files, I was hoping not to have to go and convert each one. I will choose this as the correct answer, but I'm still a bit confused by the apparently incorrect documentation and the apparent case that Microsoft doesn't support Excel for this.

Comment: Here's the page that lists Excel as supported for Azure ML Studio: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-data-science-import-data/

Comment: I will reach out to the contacts I have on that team and get clarification.

Comment: Thanks, Brian - I actually wondered this but couldn't tell if the conversion was happening or not. I didn't see anything that indicated it was csv once it was uploaded. I'll look again.

Comment: @MarkEvans Following your question. Did you get the answer ? Does it allow to upload the xlsx file as xlsx ? I can upload the file as csv ..but running into encoding warnings. Appreciate any help. thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Yes, it does convert to csv.